# gitlab CI build runs on my local docker container

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, local, gitlab

I've been trying gitlab and its CI workflow these days, but found myself confused when I saw these messages during a build:

    `gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.6.2 (3227f0a)
    Using Docker executor with image mydocker:latest ...
    Running on runner-5498280b-project-20053-concurrent-0 via jls-MacBook-Pro...`

I register a project specified runner instead of using the shared ones. 
Is gitlab actually running all the CI build process via my own machine? What if  other co-workers push to this project while my computer was off? I just thought that gitlab would provide every project with a cloud CI server... So , I don't want to turn my own computer into such a server. Am I missing something on its docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [Gitlab Docs](http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-docker-integration-works)

Is gitlab actually running all the CI build process via my own machine?

--Yes, Because you specified it. If you don't want to run into your machine, Then deploy the docker to other server.

What if other co-workers push to this project while my computer was off?

--Then, no build will going to happen,

Comment: Thanks for confirming this!! It helps